# Send Message Directly through a Port in Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Basically, I have saved a command that connects to a specific port in order to message in Terminal with another Mac.

```
$ nc -n -v -l (port)

$ nc -n -v (ip) (port) # -->  When the .command file is opened, will run directly.
```

However, when the .command file is opened the entire feed just stops. I would like it to send a message immediately then close the connection. What would the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the connection listening you would use `-kl` (keep listening).

```
nc -n -v -kl (port)
```

With the other connection you can immediately send data and close the connection by:

```
nc -n -v (ip) (port) < <(echo "hello, world!")
```

The listening connection should stay alive and wait for further connections...